# Реализация переключения массива textbox

Tags: c#, winforms

Есть ли более правильный способ переключения Enable у textbox?

В Комбобокс 50 элементов , они все сгруппированы (1-3,4-15, 16, 17, 18-20 ит.д.) при выборе соответствующего индекса комбобокса все текстбоксы на форме, сначала получают Enable = false , а потом включаются только необходимые для ввода. Пробовал через if , но это очень долга система. Есть ли способ надежнее и лучше? ПыСы: указал короткий пример как оно работает, сам код намного длиннее

```
public static void Enable(Guna2TextBox[] tb)
    {
        foreach (Guna2TextBox c in tb)
        {
            c.Enabled = true;
        }
    }

    public static void Select(Guna2TextBox guna2TextBox2, Guna2TextBox guna2TextBox3, Guna2TextBox guna2TextBox4, Guna2TextBox guna2TextBox5, Guna2TextBox guna2TextBox20, Guna2TextBox guna2TextBox21, Guna2TextBox guna2TextBox22, Guna2TextBox guna2TextBox23, Guna2TextBox guna2TextBox24, Guna2TextBox guna2TextBox25, Guna2TextBox guna2TextBox26, Guna2TextBox guna2TextBox27, Guna2TextBox guna2TextBox28, Guna2TextBox guna2TextBox29, Guna2TextBox guna2TextBox30, Guna2ComboBox guna2ComboBox3)
    {
        Guna2TextBox[] all = new Guna2TextBox[]
        {
            guna2TextBox2,guna2TextBox3,guna2TextBox4,guna2TextBox5,
            guna2TextBox20,guna2TextBox21,guna2TextBox22,guna2TextBox23,
            guna2TextBox23,guna2TextBox24,guna2TextBox25,guna2TextBox26,
            guna2TextBox27,guna2TextBox28,guna2TextBox29,guna2TextBox30
        };
        foreach (Guna2TextBox a in all)
        {
            a.Enabled = false;
        }
        int index = guna2ComboBox3.SelectedIndex;
        if (index == 0 || index == 1)
        {
            Guna2TextBox[] tb = new Guna2TextBox[] { guna2TextBox2, guna2TextBox3, guna2TextBox20, guna2TextBox21, guna2TextBox24 }; //
            Enable(tb);
        }
        if (index >= 2 && index <= 8)
        {
            Guna2TextBox[] tb = new Guna2TextBox[] { guna2TextBox2, guna2TextBox3, guna2TextBox24, };
            Enable(tb);
        }
        if (index == 9 || index == 10 || index == 11)
        {
            Guna2TextBox[] tb = new Guna2TextBox[] { guna2TextBox2, guna2TextBox3, guna2TextBox20 };
            Enable(tb);
        }
```

Comment: `Есть ли способ надежнее и лучше?` - не хранить и создавать контролы в коде, а использовать привязки?

Comment: Это winforms или секрет?

Comment: Кажется, вы наткнулись на ошибку проектирования интерфейса, но чтобы ее устранить, надо вообще понять, что происходит и какая задача на конкретном примере, и этот конкретный пример реализовать. А пока выглядит, что вы ошиблись и вместо того чтобы исправить изначальную ошибку, начали лепить поверх нее костыли, вот и получилось то что получилось. В любой задаче должна быть логика. В том что вы делаете, ее не видно, следовательно и решать здесь пока нечего. Вопрос задан неверно - [Ошибка XY](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/709/373567).

Comment: @aepot Да , winforms с библой контролов. 

Каждый текстбокс , это определенные данные, которые в будущем полетят в БД , но при этом документы разные , и набор этих текстбоксов разный. Чтобы у пользователя не было путаницы , я хочу выключить текстбоксы , которые не будут использоваться в документе и оставить только нужные. В даннном коде я через IF проверяю индексы комбобокса и если он совпадает с нужным документом, то включаю определенные текстбоксы, выключая лишние

Comment: Почему выключить, а не спрятать? Красоту прикрутить не забыли, а логику написать забыли. На будущее - должно быть наоборот. Выйдите и зайдите заново. :) То есть удалите этот вопрос и напишите новый, с учетом указанной мной выше ошибки. Желательно напишите демо проект (без красивых библиотек), на котором можно порешать вашу задачу и вставье его код в вопрос. Целиком, не кусками. Тег winforms указать не забудьте.

Comment: @aepot Не спрятать потому что они расположены в определенных местах) Так типо надо) Вот и думаю как и выключать. Пока что лучше способа чем через if не нашел

Comment: Зачем они расположены в определенных местах? Можно же прятать лишнее, чтобы неспрятанное друг за другом шло. Ставлю 1 рубль, что вы не слышали про `FlowLayoutPanel`, а она как раз эту проблему решает. Поизучайте прежде чем возвращаться к этому вопросу. Если понравится, сразу можно `TableLayoutPanel` поизучать.

Comment: @aepot Спасибо за наводку. Почитаю:)

Comment: Попробуйте реализовать задачу: есть 3 типа геометрических фигур: треугольник, прямоугольник и окружность. Реализуйте форму так, чтобы при выборе типа фигуры комбобоксе отображались только те контролы с лейблами, которые нужны для введения данных и кнопка "нарисовать", которая рисует фигуру в пикчербоксе рядом, очищая пикчербокс перед рисованием каждой фигуры. Например для треугольника надо задать 3 вершины, для прямоугольника координаты точки, высоту и ширину, для окружности - координаты центра и радиуса. Можно еще цвет линии с выбором в комбобоксе добавить. Похоже на то что вы делаете?

Comment: Можно еще рядом листбокс с введенными фигурами, куда все введенные данные добавляются, переключаясь между пунктами пикчербокс будет рисовать фигуру. Подсказка: базовый класс или интерфейс Figure, у него 3 наследника. Коллекция `BindingList<Figure> figures`, метод который рендерит контролы в панель в зависимости от типа текущей фигуры. `listbox1.DataSource = figures`. Для вывода в листбокс можно переопределить `ToString()` у наследников. Почти все решение рассказал. :)